# Storing values according to their hash values in a table but weird runtime garbage value at some positions

Tags: c++17, hashtable

Here's the code(C++)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,n,b;
    cout<<"Enter bucket size:";
    cin>>a;
    int arr[a];
    cout<<"\nHow many elements to store?";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter element "<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>b;
        int result = b%a;
        arr[result] = b;
    }
    cout<<"\nIndex\t\tData"<<endl;
    for(int j = 0;j<a;j++)
    {
        if(j==arr[j]%a)
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t\t"<<arr[j]<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t\t"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test case 1(Successful)-image 1[1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efWZv.png)
Test case 2(Unsuccessful)-image 2[2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phVML.png)
Test case 3(Unexpected fix)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,n,b;
    cout<<"Enter bucket size:";
    cin>>a;
    int arr[a];
    cout<<"\nHow many elements to store?";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter element "<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>b;
        int result = b%a;
        arr[result] = b;
    }
    //cout
    cout<<"\nIndex\t\tData"<<endl;
    
    for(int j = 0;j<a;j++)
    {
        if(j==arr[j]%a)
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t\t"<<arr[j]<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<j<<"\t\t"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[3rd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8VwY.png)

I wanted simple output of all elements getting stored but for some test cases unnecessary values and garbage values were getting stored. Also, why did adding one line fix it? I need explanation for all of it, please

Comment: The values in `int arr[a];` are uninitialized. If you don't write over all of them the ones that are left uninitialized could be any value. Consider using `std::vector` instead so you can control what the values are initialized to and because variable length arrays are not standard C++. They will not work with all compilers.